# sorting output order same as input string order

Tags: python, string, sorting, nlp

I have two strings, an input and an output, when it's passed to my required algorithm I get a qualified string as an output. But the order of words don't match with the input. How can I sort output order same as input order?

```
> def keyword_exctraction(self,new_text):
>         eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
>         hinglish_stopwords=pd.read_csv("stopwords_hinglish.csv")
>         hinglish_stop_words=hinglish_stopwords['Stop_words'].tolist()
>         stop=hinglish_stop_words+eng_stopwords
>         multilingual = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')
>         kw_model = KeyBERT(model=multilingual)
>         doc = new_text
>         keyword = kw_model.extract_keywords(doc, stop_words=stop,top_n=10,
>                                   use_mmr=True,diversity=0.2,highlight=False)
>         multilingual = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')
>         kw_model = KeyBERT(model=multilingual)
>         #print(keyword)
>         return keyword
> text = "i want to buy samsung smart tv 32 inch"
> keyword_extracted=self.keyword_exctraction(text)
```

result i get after running this is:
keyword extracted is.... [('samsung', 0.587), ('tv', 0.3726), ('32', 0.3405), ('inch', 0.291), ('buy', 0.288), ('smart', 0.2663)

output is : samsung tv 32 inch buy smart

Example:

```
input = "i want to buy samsung smart tv 32 inch"
output = "samsung tv 32 inch buy smart"
```

Expected result is "buy samsung smart tv 32 inch"

I've tried sort but it does not gives the required output.
How can i arrange them not according to their order and not score

Comment: Without your "required algorithm" we have no way to help you, please attach the code.

Comment: I'm guessing some details here but ' '.join((word for word in text.split() if required(word)))

Comment: i am working on keyword extraction...using Keybert.

Comment: Can you see what has happened there?  The words are sorted in order of importance.  You can certainly split your input string, and look up each word in your result list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the long version of my original comment:

First, let me ignore the extraction details by just hardcoding that data here:

```
text = 'i want to buy samsung smart tv 32 inch'
keyword_extraction = [
    ('samsung', 0.587), 
    ('tv', 0.3726), 
    ('32', 0.3405), 
    ('inch', 0.291), 
    ('buy', 0.288), 
    ('smart', 0.2663)
]
```

In order to sort them by their position in the original text, just ... do that. This is the naive implementation. Looking up each index is inefficient and may not give the output you want if a word appears multiple times or is a substring of another word.

```
just_the_keywords = [x[0] for x in keyword_extraction]
just_the_keywords.sort(key=lambda word : text.find(word))
print (just_the_keywords)
```

However, I would not sort them. I would instead just iterate over the original words, but only extract the keywords. That way you get the original order without having to perform a sort. Note the use of a set for the "in" operator.

```
keywords = set(just_the_keywords)
sorted_keywords = [word for word in text.split() if word in keywords]
```

And of course it is easy to change the list of words to a single string.

```
print(' '.join(sorted_keywords))
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely help @Kenny Ostrom

Comment: Hey, revisiting - I probably should have mentioned you can pass keyword_extraction to the builtin dict constructor and use that instead of a set. Just in case you ever need those values.